# $\left\| \begin{pmatrix} 0 &A\\ A^* &0 \end{pmatrix}\right\|=\|A\|.$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $E$ be a complex Hilbert space, with inner product $\langle\cdot\;, \;\cdot\rangle$ and the norm $\|\cdot\|$ and let $\mathcal{L}(E)$ the algebra of all operators on $E$.

> Let $A\in\mathcal{L}(E)$. I want to prove that
>   $$\left\| \begin{pmatrix}
> 0 &A\\
> A^* &0
> \end{pmatrix}\right\|=\|A\|.$$
>   Here $\begin{pmatrix}
> 0 &A\\
> A^* &0
> \end{pmatrix}\in \mathcal{L}(E\oplus E)$.

**Attempt** \begin{align*}
\left\| \begin{pmatrix}
0 &A\\
A^* &0
\end{pmatrix}\right\| &= \sup_{\substack{a\in E^2\\\|a\|^2=1}} \left\| 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 &A\\
A^* &0
\end{pmatrix}\cdot a\right\|\\
&= \sup_{\substack{x\in E,y\in E\\\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2=1}} \left\| 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 &A\\
A^* &0
\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}
x\\y
\end{pmatrix}\right\|\\
&= \sup_{\substack{x\in E,y\in E\\\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2=1}}  \left\| 
\begin{pmatrix}
Ay\\A^*x
\end{pmatrix}\right\|\\
&= \sup_{\substack{x\in E,y\in E\\\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2=1}} \|Ay\|^2+\|A^*x\|^2=1\\
&=????\|A\|
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $B$ be the big matrix, then
$\|B \binom{x}{y} \|^2 = \|Ay\|^2+\|A^*x\|^2 = \|Ay\|^2+\|Ax\|^2 \le \|A\|^2 ( \|x\|^2 + \|y\|^2)$.

It is immediate from this that $\|B\| \le \|A\|$, and from $\|B \binom{0}{y} \|^2 = \|Ay\|^2$ that $\|B\| = \|A\|$.

**Addendum**:

Note that $\|A^*x\| = \sup_{\|u\| \le 1} | \langle u, A^* x \rangle = \sup_{\|u\| \le 1} | \langle Au, x \rangle  \le \|A\| \|x\|$, so $\|A^*\| \le \|A\|$.
Since $(A^*)^* = A$, we get $\|A\| \le \|A^*\|$.

Comment: Please I think you made a mistake because $\|A^*x\|$ is not in general equal to $\|Ax\|$

Comment: See the addendum...

Answer (score 0):

An other way to see this:
$$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & A\\ A^* & 0\end{pmatrix}$$
corresponds to the operator $X$ on $E\oplus E$ given by
$$X(\xi\oplus \eta) = A\eta \oplus A^*\xi$$
i.e., $X$ is the composition of the switch map $\xi\oplus \eta \mapsto \eta \oplus \xi$ (which is a unitary!) with the direct sum operator $A\oplus A^*$. Hence, the norm of your matrix is simply $\|A \oplus A^*\| = \max\{\|A\|, \|A^*\|\}= \|A\|$.

Comment: Sorry for intruding but I'd like to say that I have a comment for you in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4464923/aa-1-unitary-for-a-in-a-unital-c-algebra/4465027?noredirect=1#comment9357303_4465027, which might not trigger a notification since you deleted your own comment.