# $a|a|^{-1}$ unitary for $a$ in a unital $C^*$-algebra?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a unital $C^*$-algebra and $a ∈ A$ arbitrary. I have already shown that for $a ∈ \text{Inv}(A)$, we have $|a| := \sqrt{a^*a} ∈ \text{Inv}(A)$, so we can indeed, for $a ∈ \text{Inv}(A)$, define $u := a|a|^{-1}$ so that $a = u|a|$. (I see that we are essentially '*normalising*' the element $a$, insofar as that is meaningful here.)

Now we can just compute:

$$u^{-1} = |a|a^{-1} = \sqrt{a^*a}a^{-1} = (a^*)^{\frac{1}{2}}a^{\frac{1}{2}}a^{-1} = (a^*)^{\frac{1}{2}}a^{-\frac{1}{2}} = \sqrt{a^*a^{-1}}
$$
and
$$u^* = (a|a|^{-1})^* = (|a|^{-1})^*a^* = \left(\left(\sqrt{a^*a}\right)^{-1}\right)^*a^* = \left((a^*a)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\right)^*a^* = (a^*a)^{-\frac{1}{2}}a^* = a^{-\frac{1}{2}}(a^*)^{\frac{1}{2}} = (a^{-1})^{\frac{1}{2}}(a^*)^{\frac{1}{2}} = \sqrt{a^{-1}a^*} 
$$

So apparently, if $u$ is to be unitary (i.e., $u^* = u^{-1}$), we must have that $a^{-1}$ commutes with $a^*$, but I see no reason to assume that.

Comment: You make some dubious manipulations. For example, $\sqrt{a^\ast a}=\sqrt{a^\ast}\sqrt{a}$ does not make sense unless $a$ is positive.

Comment: I agree with @MaoWao.  Why would $\sqrt{a^*a} = \sqrt{a^*}\sqrt{a}$ when we do not even have $(a^*a)^2 = (a^*)^2 a^2$ [unless $a$ is normal]  Also, I think in general $a$ and $|a|$ do not commute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, $u:=|a|a^{-1}$ is unitary.  To prove it one computes
$$
u^*u = (a^*)^{-1}|a|^2a^{-1}= $$$$=(a^*)^{-1}a^*aa^{-1}= 1,
$$
while
$$
uu^* = |a|a^{-1}(a^*)^{-1}|a|= $$$$
=|a|(a^*a)^{-1}|a|
=|a||a|^{-2}|a|=1.$$

Comment: @QuantumSpace, what is your definition of unitary?  As far as I know  an element $u$ in a $C^*$-algebra is unitary if $uu^*=1=u^*u$.  This is equivalent to saying that $u^*=u^{-1}$.

Comment: Ah you just have the factors mixed up: I am trying to compute $a|a|^{-1}$, not $|a|a^{-1}$. But your answer was still useful since it showed me I didn't need to fool around with the square roots as $a^*a = |a|^2$ :)

Comment: @JosvanNieuwman. Oh dear, I did mess up with the order of terms!  I am very sorry!  Nevertheless, $a|a|^{-1}$ is the inverse of $|a|a^{-1}$,
and it is obvious that the inverse of a unitary element is unitary!

Comment: @QuantumSpace, Only now do I understand your comment.  I first took it to mean my proof was not enough but now I see that you were pointing to my mistaking $a|a|^{-1}$ for $|a|a^{-1}$.  Sorry!